# Sample code for Magento 2 Modal popup

Tags: magento2

I Request you to provide the sample code for magento2 popup modal. I have tried with magento Ui library and its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can open modal popup using the below code

```
    <script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'popup modal title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```